# How to convert generic numbers to Double in swift?

Tags: swift, generics, double

I've made a class with generic type T, where T should only be a numeric value (`CGFloat`, `Double`, `Int`, etc.) and should be able to be converted to `Double`. I've tried several types, like `Numeric` and `Equatable`, but those still cast the net too wide. When converting to `Double` the type should conform to either `BinaryInteger` or `BinaryFloatingPoint` but I've yet to find a way to let a generic conform to either one of two types.

What I want:

```
class SomeClass<T:SomeNumberTypeThatAllowsConversionToDouble> {
    var number: T
    var doubleNumber: Double
    init(number: T) {
        self.number = number
        self.doubleNumber = Double(number) //or some other function that converts from T to Double
    }
}
```

What I don't want is two separate extensions to `SomeClass` where one handles the `BinaryInteger` case and one the `BinaryFloatingPoint` case, since that would defeat the purpose of why I'm using generics in the first place.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you need to be able to convert any numeric type to `Double`?

Comment: What do you mean by *but those still cast the net too wide* ?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I'm converting different objects, which store numeric values as different types, to one, and want to keep their original types while also having one universal type. I chose `Double` for this, but it could have just as well been another type.

Comment: @M.Koot that didn't really answer my question. If you are trying to create a generic storage for numeric values, why can't you make the storage itself generic, why do you need to represent all numbers with the same type? What practical problem are you trying to solve with this? I'm asking this, because there isn't really a good solution to the problem you are asking about, however, it feels to me, this isn't your real problem, but an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). So it very well might be possible to solve your actual problem.

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi I meant it figuratively. `Numeric` can include more than just 'numbers' so long as they have some form of multiplication, `Equatable` idem is not constrained enough. (E.g. an array could be made `Numeric` but can't be naturally converted to a single `Double`)  I just want to include normal 'number' types.

Comment: @DávidPásztor This is the problem I'm trying to solve. It's a problem of elegance. You're right that my underlying problem can be solved in different ways, one of which I named in the question: I can simply use extensions. But I feel as though the generic format can and should support some sort of universal 'number' type. It seems as though there should be a generic/agnostic way for numbers to be converted into each other — especially when there's no precision loss.

Comment: You can try `NSNumber` but the caller would have to do some conversions in cases like `Float`

Comment: @M.Koot sadly this is simply not possible with the current type system of Swift. The numeric Swift protocols could still use some improvements, but there are valid reasons for why they were implemented the were they were, mostly due to the low-level arithmetic differences between different numeric types. Creating 2 generic inits for your type, one taking a `BinaryInteger`, the other a `BinaryFloatingPoint` could be a solution, however, sadly the Swift type system cannot deal with such type constraints (generic init specialising an already generic type) as of yet.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks for your explanation. I'll leave the question open, should anyone find a creative solution or should this behaviour change in future versions of swift, but for now I've gone the (inelegant) route of using extensions, and just basically writing the same code twice.

Answer (score 3):

What you would like achieve is constraint T to conform to  a fixed group of protocol.

It is very similar to what we have in Typescript `T:number|point|size` ( union type mentioned by @Dávid Pásztor )

below is my workaround in Swift.It is not that neat and maybe we can have better solution.

```
protocol DoubleConvertible { }

extension Int:DoubleConvertible { }
extension CGFloat:DoubleConvertible { }
extension Double:DoubleConvertible {
    static func convert(_ number:DoubleConvertible) -> Double {
        if let intNumber = number as? Int {
            return Double(intNumber)
        } else if let cgFloatNumber = number as? CGFloat {
            return Double(cgFloatNumber)
        } else if let doubleNumber = number as? Double{
            return Double(doubleNumber)
        } else {
            assertionFailure()
        }
    }
}

import UIKit

class SomeClass<T> where T:DoubleConvertible {
    var number: T
    var doubleNumber: Double
    init(number: T) {
        self.number = number
        self.doubleNumber = Double.convert(number)
    }
}

print(SomeClass<Int>(number: 10).doubleNumber)
print(SomeClass<Double>(number: 10.0).doubleNumber)
print(SomeClass<CGFloat>(number: CGFloat(integerLiteral: 10)).doubleNumber)

//10.0
//10.0
//10.0

print(SomeClass<CGPoint>(number: 10).doubleNumber)
//Type 'CGPoint' does not conform to protocol 'DoubleConvertible'
```

Comment: Using the `is` operator to type check a value and then force cast it to that type is a very bad idea. Instead, use safe casting like `if let int = number as? Int { return Double(int) }`. And don't do force casting in your if branch either, instead cover all supported types using `if` branches and throw a fatal error or simply return a default value after an `assertionFailure` in the default `else` branch. Also, what you mention in TypeScript is called a union type.

Comment: @DávidPásztor upgrade according to your suggestion.